# Averaging multiple columns and ignore any 0% values excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Using Excel 2007, im attempting to find the average of the following cells

> F5, I5, L5, O5, R5, U5, X5, AA5, AD5, AG5, AJ5, AM5

Each column is a percentage and the average is required to gain their overall average for the year.

I've tried to use the following:

```
=AVERAGEIF(F5,I5,L5,O5,R5,U5,X5,AA5,AD5,AG5,AJ5,AM5,">0")
```

This just gives me an error message saying i have used too many arguments for the function.

I also attempted to use this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(F5,I5,L5,O5,R5,U5,X5,AA5,AD5,AG5,AJ5,AM5),IF(F5,I5,L5,O5,R5,U5,X5,AA5,AD5,AG5,AJ5,AM5<>0,F5,I5,L5,O5,R5,U5,X5,AA5,AD5,AG5,AJ5,AM5)))
```

But again i got the same error message that i have used too many arguments for the function.

Is there a better a way to find the average of all these cells or get the averageif function recognise multiple columns.

Comment: my apologies i must of overheard my colleague who was talking about columns as i was writing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any headers that can distinguish the columns to average? If so then you can use an `AVERAGEIFS` formula like this

`=AVERAGEIFS(F5:AM5,F5:AM5,"> 0",F$2:AM$2,"total")`

where row 2 contains headers and only the columns you want - F, I, L etc. contain the value "total" (without quotes). Adjust text as required

If you don't have such a header row then you can use this "array formula" to average every 3rd cell in your range (assuming it's >0)

`=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(F5:AM5)-COLUMN(F5),3)=0,IF(F5:AM5>0,F5:AM5)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>